# How to properly create textures using DSA for ImageTexture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, texture, compute-shader

For the old approach, generating a texture for the ImageTexture for compute shaders would look like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, (GLsizei)m_width, (GLsizei)m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
```

However, in DSA, glTexImage2D is no longer a thing and we need to use `glTextureStorage2D` and `glTextureSubImage2D` to replace it.
Yet, the new DSA functions don't work with ImageTextures, when I try to create texture for the ImageTextures, the texture returns black. Here is the code:

```
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_texture);
glTextureStorage2D(m_texture, 0, m_internalFormat, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);

glTextureParameteri(m_texture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTextureParameteri(m_texture, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTextureParameteri(m_texture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureParameteri(m_texture, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextureSubImage2D(m_texture, 0, 0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, m_dataFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
```

I've read about that the new DSA functions are immutable textures and maybe that causes this problem? If that is the case, what is the DSA counterpart for creating mutable textures?

Comment: What do you mean by "image texture"?

Comment: You cannot pass a `nullptr` to `glTex(ture)SubImage*D`. If you don't want to fill the texture with data, then just don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

The **2nd argument** of glTextureStorage2D() API is **mip-map levels**, if you specify it as **0**, it causes troubles you may have.

```
glTextureStorage2D(m_texture, 0, m_internalFormat, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);
```